# Spring Integration - Send message immediately after FTP download

Tags: java, spring, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, spring-integration

Is there a way to have Spring Integration's FTP Inbound Channel Adapter (actually I'm using the S3 Inbound Channel adapter, but they're very similar) fire off a message for each file it has downloaded, as soon as it has downloaded it? I have a very large directory, and I want to process files as soon as they arrive on my local filesystem, instead of waiting for the whole directory to get downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the s3 project supports it yet, but in FTP, one could use the ftp-outbound-gateway, which allows commands such as `ls`, `get`, `rm` etc. This would allow you to list the folder, split the list, and issue a separate `get` for each file, as is shown in the sample.

https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/ftp

Comment: Thanks Gary. Are there any plans to roll the AWS project into the main project?

Comment: The author's pull request is under review - to pull the AWS project into the extensions repository. https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration-extensions/pulls - I am sure he will take a look at implementing the gateway at some point.